# Is there a port of android layouts for Swing?

Tags: android, swing, layout

I mainly develop for android, but sometimes I need to write a small PC tool, in which case I use Swing. However I always have problems with the Swing layouts, so I was wondering if there is a port of the android layouts for Swing? For example an implementation of RelativeLayout, LinearLayout, etc.

Comment: MigLayout is otherwise a fine piece of kit if using Swing is giving you a bad taste in your mouth. Tjenare semc:are btw.

Comment: AFAIK there is no such a monstrosity. MigLayout is OK :) or use WYSIWYG tool like a NetBeans Matis.